# After a Location.go(), History.back() does not trigger ActivatedRoute.paramMap

Tags: angular, angular-routing, browser-history

Consider this URL:

`http://localhost:4200/items`

I use **Location.go() to update the URL** when an element is opened (expanded) in my GUI:

```
http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=123
```

When I hit the back button, the URL is changed back to http://localhost:4200/items, but my subscription on ActivatedRoute.paramMap **is not triggered**. (and therefore my item is stays opened)

**Oddly enough, it is triggered when I open two elements consecutively, and then hit back two times:**

```
Open main page -> http://localhost:4200/items
Open item 123  -> http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=123
Open item 456  -> http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=456

Back to http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=123 -> ActivatedRoute.paramMap triggered
Back to http://localhost:4200/items -> ActivatedRoute.paramMap triggered (!)
```

Why isnt't it triggered the first time? Why do I need to have two history entries before it works? I am confused.

Update: This is how I listen for changes in the paramMap:

```
  public ngOnInit() {

    this.subscriptions.add(this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap => {
      this.handleNavigation(paramMap);
    }));
}
```

Comment: u are using paramMap as observable or not?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question.

Comment: something special thing to use Location.go() and not router.navigate?

Comment: I had that before. I changed it so that the complexity of handleNavigation remains low. I also track opened tabs in the url (like this https://medium.com/agilix/change-the-route-without-reloading-in-angular-7a4aa82a8d3e )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced the same issue, I guess it's because the [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) doesn't know about the `location.go()` navigation. So, `location.go()` changes location url to `http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=123` but the router current url is still `http://localhost:4200/items`. When you press back, router ignores the event because the 'back' url matches the current router url. If you call `location.go()` twice and navigate back, the `back` url is `http://localhost:4200/items;openedId=123` and doesn't match the router url, so `paramMap` is triggered.

A workaround may be to add some unique param to the url, like current timestamp, I tried and it works, but it isn't the best solution definitely. I ended up using [Route.navigate()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) instead of `location.go()`. If you want to filter some navigations, it's possible by passing [state](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) to the `navigate` method, afterwards you can filter navigations by accessing the state via [Router.getCurrentNavigation()](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#getcurrentnavigation).

The problem is that the Location isn't designed for route changes, the service [documentation tells](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#usage-notes):

> It's better to use the Router#navigate service to trigger route changes. Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is there any way to change the router's state (to trick it into thinking that it changed after a location.go)?

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately I haven't found a way. May be there is an answer in the [Router sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.14/packages/router/src/router.ts#L278-L1126). I've also added a quote from the Location documentation to the answer, which suggests to use Router instead of Location for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend using the Location.go() function.

The best recommendation that I could make is to add a click event on the element in your GUI. the click event would call a function.

`<div (click)="focusLocation('<INSERT LOCATION ID HERE>')">YOUR CONTENT</div>`

```
focusLocation(queryParam) {
  this.router.navigate(['/items'], { queryParams: { openedId: queryParam } });
}
```

This should always activate the `activatedRoute.params.subscribe(() => {});`

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but I had navigation before. I intentionally changed it to location.go. I just want to understand how it works.